# Combining data frames in R without overwriting data with blanks

Tags: r

**RStudio Version 1.3.959 (what I'm using)**, R version 4.0.2, MacOS Catalina, version 10.15.5.

Maybe I'm overthinking this, but I haven't been able to find a function that can do what I need:
I have two data frames with 533 columns and 10,338 rows, both with identical formatting. Values are missing from `df_all_data` (values labeled as `outlier`) that I have in `df_outliers`, which doesn't contain the values from df_all_data. I would like to combine, somehow, df_all_data and `df_outliers` without the blanks in `df_outliers` overwriting the values in the cells in `df_all_data`. For example, in Excel, in special paste you can say `ignore blanks`. All that I want to overwrite are the cells filled with `outlier` which mark where the data from `df_outliers` go. There are true missing data which is why there are NAs. Condensed example data frames are below:

```
df_outliers = data.frame(Reference.Mass = c(256.2402292, 257.0324221, 257.0357941), GC1 = c(436955360, "", NA), GC2 = c(480996256, "", ""), GC3 = c(386362944, "", NA))

Reference.Mass       GC1       GC2       GC3
1       256.2402 436955360 480996256 386362944
2       257.0324                              
3       257.0358      <NA>                <NA>

df_all_data = data.frame(Reference.Mass = c(256.2402292, 257.0324221, 257.0357941), GC1 = c("outlier", 6109980, NA), GC2 = c("outlier", 7437798, 2721256), GC3 = c("outlier", 8958061, NA))

Reference.Mass     GC1     GC2     GC3
1       256.2402 outlier outlier outlier
2       257.0324 6109980 7437798 8958061
3       257.0358    <NA> 2721256    <NA>
```

I've tried `merge`, `cbind`, `full_join`, `left_join`. None have been able to overlay `df_outliers` without overwriting `df_all_data`. There are roughly 4,000 outlier values that need to be inserted into `df_all_data` in the correct row and column. I don't want to add any rows or columns. If anyone can shed any light on whether this is possible or how to format it using one of these functions, or if there are any other options, that would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How do you identify if a row is an outlier in `df_all_data`. Is the string `outlier` present there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to overwrite, create a logical matrix and use that to assign

```
i1 <- df_all_data == 'outlier' & !is.na(df_all_data)
df_all_data[i1] <- df_outliers[i1]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! That worked perfectly for my small example but I receive an error when I try to apply it to my actual data set. GC_FTIC_2[i1] <- GC_FTIC_3[il]
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i1, value = c("436955360", "238912608",  : 
  unsupported matrix index in replacement

Comment: @sacrebleucarbon What is the error?  Do you have `factor` columns?

Comment: @sacrebleucarbon. Here, I am assuming that both of the datasets have the same dimensions

Comment: The numbers used in my examples came straight from my data set. And yes, both 10,338 rows and 533 columns. They're character columns

Comment: @sacrebleucarbon Can you the `class` of the columns and change it to `character` if there are any `factor` columns i.e. `i2 <- sapply(df_all_data, is.factor); df_all_data[i2] <- lapply(df_all_data[i2], as.character)` as the error is not clear to me

Comment: They're already character, except for the first column of reference masses which is numeric but that was the same for the data I provided

Comment: @sacrebleucarbon can you try on the fresh data, with `length(df_all_data[i1])` and `length(df_outliers[i1])` before doing the assignment

Comment: I fixed the error; I think there was an l typed instead of a 1 or something like that when I tried to change it but it works now! Thank you so much! Wow I should have posted this question days ago haha